# Magento 2: Menu categories in one line

Tags: magento2

I created a static concent with brands:
[image]

The only problem is that how can I display it in one line?

New arrivals, Luxury, Low Cost, We love it.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="mega-menu-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">NEW ARRIVALS</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}ikat-tiered-tank-dress.html">Saucony<span class="label-menu" style="background-color: #ec0101; border-color: #ec0101; right: -12px;">Hot</span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">Ray-Ban</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}wholesale-fashion-handbags-store-fashion.html">Brikenstock</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-hot-fire-brown-store-fashion.html">Micheal Kors</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}josie-floral-outfit-set-store-fashion.html">Ralph Lauren</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}meena-floral-blackless-dress-store-fashion.html">Versace Jeans</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}pink-leather-watch-store-fashion.html">Marvel</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-lion-king-black-store-fashion.html">Star Wars</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">Dsquared2</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">LUXURY</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=en">Philip Plein</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=fr">Dolce&amp;Gabbana</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=de">Fontana 2.0</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">Brooks Brothers</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cyan-boheme-store-fashion.html">Trussardi</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}denim-shell-top-with-ruffle-front-store-fashion.html">Cavalli Class</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}short-sleeved-hoodie-store-fashion.html">Versace</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cuffed-beanie-store-fashion.html">Valentino</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}tactical-rush-moab-store-fashion.html">Moschino</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">LOW COST</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=en">Jaggy</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=fr">Pierre Cardin</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=de">Carrera Jeans</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">No Limits</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cyan-boheme-store-fashion.html">Sergio Tacchini</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}denim-shell-top-with-ruffle-front-store-fashion.html">Elle Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}short-sleeved-hoodie-store-fashion.html">Cesare Paciotti</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cuffed-beanie-store-fashion.html">Guru</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}tactical-rush-moab-store-fashion.html">Police</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">WE LOVE IT</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=en">Pierre Cardin</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=fr">Made in Italia</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=de">Fontana 2.0</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">Ana Lublin</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}denim-shell-top-with-ruffle-front-store-fashion.html">Oxford University</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}short-sleeved-hoodie-store-fashion.html">Geographical Norway</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cuffed-beanie-store-fashion.html">Sparco</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}tactical-rush-moab-store-fashion.html">U.S. Polo</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

@ update
[image]

Comment: Could you please share URL ?

Comment: @Sylvester you are doing this code by static block?

Comment: yes, I have add this code in static content. I updated my subject

Comment: You want this https://prnt.sc/kaggcn

Comment: Hello @Sylvester, Did you tried my solution ?

Comment: Hello Pawn, yes all works perfect. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to `col-md-3` from `col-md-6`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. changed col-md-6 to col-md-3

```
<div class="mega-menu-content">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">NEW ARRIVALS</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}ikat-tiered-tank-dress.html">Saucony<span class="label-menu" style="background-color: #ec0101; border-color: #ec0101; right: -12px;">Hot</span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">Ray-Ban</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}wholesale-fashion-handbags-store-fashion.html">Brikenstock</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-hot-fire-brown-store-fashion.html">Micheal Kors</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}josie-floral-outfit-set-store-fashion.html">Ralph Lauren</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}meena-floral-blackless-dress-store-fashion.html">Versace Jeans</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}pink-leather-watch-store-fashion.html">Marvel</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-lion-king-black-store-fashion.html">Star Wars</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">Dsquared2</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">LOW COST</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=en">Jaggy</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=fr">Pierre Cardin</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=de">Carrera Jeans</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">No Limits</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cyan-boheme-store-fashion.html">Sergio Tacchini</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}denim-shell-top-with-ruffle-front-store-fashion.html">Elle Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}short-sleeved-hoodie-store-fashion.html">Cesare Paciotti</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cuffed-beanie-store-fashion.html">Guru</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}tactical-rush-moab-store-fashion.html">Police</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">LUXURY</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=en">Philip Plein</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=fr">Dolce&amp;Gabbana</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=de">Fontana 2.0</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">Brooks Brothers</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cyan-boheme-store-fashion.html">Trussardi</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}denim-shell-top-with-ruffle-front-store-fashion.html">Cavalli Class</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}short-sleeved-hoodie-store-fashion.html">Versace</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cuffed-beanie-store-fashion.html">Valentino</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}tactical-rush-moab-store-fashion.html">Moschino</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="mega-menu-sub-title">WE LOVE IT</span></a> <span class="toggle-menu hidden-lg"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="fa fa-plus"> </span> </a> </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=en">Pierre Cardin</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=fr">Made in Italia</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html?___store=de">Fontana 2.0</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-super-man-store-fashion.html">Ana Lublin</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}denim-shell-top-with-ruffle-front-store-fashion.html">Oxford University</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}short-sleeved-hoodie-store-fashion.html">Geographical Norway</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}cuffed-beanie-store-fashion.html">Sparco</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}tactical-rush-moab-store-fashion.html">U.S. Polo</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}jean-raw-denim-black-store-fashion.html">&gt;&gt;pokaż wszystkie&lt;&lt;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```